# How to use google chrome into novnc or localhhost

Tags: ubuntu, x11vnc

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install firefox -y && groupadd -g 1000 ubuntu && useradd -d /home/ubuntu -s /bin/bash -m ubuntu -u 1000 -g 1000
USER ubuntu
ENV HOME /home/ubuntu
CMD /usr/bin/firefox
```

this will create a container with firefox.
can i use this dockerfile and modified to get chrome browser.
And how to connect that chrome browser to novnc or x11 server display.

when i `echo $DISPLAY` i am getting blank

I used the following commands

```
apt-get install xorg xauth openbox -y
```

I am doing all this in a freshly installed ubuntu in cloud

Comment: why would you use firefox to get chrome? Just install chrome, or directly `chromium` (as packaged in ubuntu).

Comment: I want to install chrome inside a docker and get that in novnc I just showed example of firefox install in docker that i found online

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run graphical applications on docker containers is to directly mount the X11 socket into the container. To do that, add the following argument the your `docker run` command :

```
-v /tmp/.X11-unix/:/tmp/.X11-unix/
```

You also need to grant access to the X server. You can do so by also mounting the `.Xauthority` file (`xauth` must be installed in the container) :

```
-v ~/.Xauthority:/home/ubuntu/.Xauthority
```

Alternatively, you can use `xhost +` on the host but it is not recommended.

And don't forget to set the `DISPLAY` variable with :

```
-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

You don't need to install any X Server or Window Manager on the container.